# FB objective c sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share a video to facebook but for some reason nothing is shared.  I tried it earlier with a image and it worked but when i tried the video it didnt work. Can you not share video to facebook unless its on a web server or something?

Object Code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_movie" ofType:@"mov"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];



NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object.provisionedForPost = YES;

// for og:title
object[@"title"] = @"Roasted pumpkin seeds";

// for og:type, this corresponds to the Namespace you've set for your app and the object type name
object[@"type"] = @"namespace:video.other";

object[@"video"] = videoData;
```

Code:

```
-(void)ShareFB {


[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error){
                              NSDictionary *permissions= [(NSArray *)[result data] objectAtIndex:0];
                              if (![permissions objectForKey:@"publish_actions"]){
                                  // Permission hasn't been granted, so ask for publish_actions
                                  [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                                                        defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                                          if (!error) {
                                                                              if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
                                                                                  // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not share to Facebook
                                                                                  NSLog(@"Permission not granted, we will not share to Facebook.");

                                                                              } else {
                                                                                  // Permission granted, publish the OG story
                                                                                  [self facebookSharing];
                                                                              }

                                                                          } else {
                                                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                                              NSLog(@"Encountered an error requesting permissions: %@", error.description);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }];

                              } else {
                                  // Permissions present, publish the OG story
                                  [self facebookSharing];
                              }

                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                              NSLog(@"Encountered an error checking permissions: %@", error.description);
                          }
                      }];

}


// When the user is done picking the image
- (void)facebookSharing
{
    // Get the image
  //  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button"];


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_movie" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];



    NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
    object.provisionedForPost = YES;

    // for og:title
    object[@"title"] = @"Roasted pumpkin seeds";

    // for og:type, this corresponds to the Namespace you've set for your app and the object type name
    object[@"type"] = @"namespace:video.other";

    object[@"video"] = videoData;


    // Post custom object
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            // get the object ID for the Open Graph object that is now stored in the Object API
            NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSLog(@"object id: %@", objectId);

            // create an Open Graph action
            id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
            [action setObject:objectId forKey:@"video.other"];

            // create action referencing user owned object
            [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/namespace:record" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if(!error) {
                    NSLog(@"OG story posted, story id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OG story posted"
                                                message:@"Check your Facebook profile or activity log to see the story."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                } else {
                    // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                    // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                    NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
                }
            }];

        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
        }
    }];


}
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting.  In its current state, the code is unreadable.

Comment: the code is unreadable...but just to get started: set a breakpoint at "[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object" and tell us what 'object' is.

Comment: thats how the code was in xcode, how do i make it more reasonable.  The object is a video file, updated my question showing how object is created.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?  What error is being returned?

Comment: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 1.)   The video doesnt get shared.

Comment: @swiftlearner Most of the people said that, add with your permission "public_stream" for video share. But, that people code doesn't go to permission condition if the user were already logged. So, can't share the video. Am also facing problem in video share.